# Where can I find my saved wifi passwords on 14.04?

Tags: networking, wireless, password

Trying to connect my phone to my girlfriend's home network. My laptop already has it saved from a previous visit, but I've forgotten what it was and the sticker with the router's default pass code has been removed. Is there a way that I can access a list of the already-saved network passwords for my system?

Comment: You can find them in Network Manager.

Comment: How do I access Network Manager?

Comment: It does not look like you are using Ubuntu ;-) It is a network icon on top.

Comment: Haha rest assured, I am. Just *very* new and didn't know you were referring to the wifi icon near the top-right of the screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on the wifi icon in the menu bar and choose `edit connections`. Select the network you wish from the list and press `edit`. Go to the 'Wi-Fi security' tab, and there's an option `Show password`

And if you want to do this from the terminal type this in:

`sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/the-name-of-your-network`, and it will be under an entry `psk`. Obviously put the name of your network under the-name-of-your-network. To make it easier, you can press tab twice after typing in `sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` and you will see the available files, one of which will be your network.

Comment: I also added instructions how to do this from the temrinal

Answer (score 3):

Wifi passwords can be found in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. There is a file for each connection with its configuration, also you need root privileges to read them but the password isn't encrypted. You can use `sudo nautilus` for easy access to the file